# Moving window with two conditions - Matlab

Tags: matlab, window, highlight, threshold

I have a time series data with the amplitude of the values range from 1 to 100. I need to use a moving window (10 seconds duration) and flag/highlight the segments of the data that falls with the threshold range of 91 to 97 for at least 10 seconds or more. The data is available in the following link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx7z9qzg8gxb4x3/data.mat?dl=0

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

I have used the following code:

```
`x= load('data.mat');
time = 1:length(x);
window = 1000; % 10 second window - data was sampled at 100Hz.
[TF,L,U,C] = isoutlier(x); % I tried to find outlier
figure;
plot(time,x,time(TF),x(TF),'*')
legend('Data','Outlier')
figure;
plot(time,x,time(TF),x(TF),'x',time,93*ones(1,length(x)),time,
97*ones(1,length(x)))`
```

I get the following figure [https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZa9m.jpg]
But not sure. How to use this as threshold windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not fully defined and cannot be answered as it stands. Please read [how to ask](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwn6aCn9XlAhWioVwKHXN1CNcQFjADegQICxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58722458/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: Dear Hoki, thanks. I have a data. Is there anyway I can upload them?

Comment: You cannot upload them here but you can upload them somewhere and provide a link for it. However this will not complete your question. A better solution would be to create a minimum sample set of data, with a clear description of what you want to do to it, and the _desired_ output. This would allow anyone to try their method and see if it answers your question right (instead of guessing what you want and maybe getting it wrong).

Comment: Hi Hoki, thanks. I have added the datalink, code and the figure. I can plot the threshold levels but cant make it to highlight/shade for 10 seconds or more window length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a way to do that with an actual sliding window, but since I had to do kind of similar operations to you in a different way, I'll reuse a function I did years ago which is perfect to approach this problem another way.

Basically the process is:

- Find ALL the indices verifying the condition (x>91 & x<97).
- Find the start and stop indices of each consecutive group/interval found in step above.
- Compute length of each interval (easy with start and stop given above)
- Discard intervals too short

By now you have a list of intervals (start and stop indices) verifying all your conditions (signal level AND duration). With that you can then:

- rebuild a single vector of valid indices
- Create a secondary vector which contains only the data flagged (the data of `x` which verified all conditions).
- display :-)

In code it looks like this:

```
%% Your inputs
load('data.mat');
time = 1:length(x);

%% Setup
winSize = 1000 ;    % Fs * Duration = 100 * 10 = 1000 points
lvlmin = 91 ;       % Minimum level to flag
lvlmax = 97 ;       % Maximum level to flag

%% Find which interval to flag
% find all the indices where the condition is true
idx = ( x>lvlmin ) & ( x<lvlmax ) ;
% get the start and stop index of each group of consecutive indices
itBounds = get_interval_boundaries( idx ) ;
% get the length of each interval/group
itLenght = diff(itBounds,1,2)+1 ; 
% only consider intervals >= winSize
it2flag = itLenght >= winSize ; 
nint = sum(it2flag) ;       % found 241 valid intervals out of 596.

%% Clear [idx] of the short intervals
itbad = itBounds( ~it2flag , : ) ; % keep only the intervals to discard
for k=1:size(itbad,1)
    idx(itbad(k,1):itbad(k,2)) = false ;
end

%% Display
flaggedTime = time(idx) ;
flaggedData = x(idx) ;

figure
plot(time,x)
hold on
plot(flaggedTime,flaggedData,'.')

lx = [time(1) time(end)] ;
plot( lx , [lvlmin lvlmin], '-.k')
plot( lx , [lvlmax lvlmax], '-.k')

%% OR, alternatively, keep vectors the same lenght by adding NaNs
flaggedData = x ;
flaggedData(~idx) = NaN ;

figure
plot(time,x)
hold on
plot(time,flaggedData)
```

And a preview of how data are flagged:
[image]

---

You'll need the code for `get_interval_boundaries.m`. I could have coded only the functionality needed in less code, but since this was available and works perfectly, no need to reinvent the wheel :

```
function itbound = get_interval_boundaries(vec)
% function itbound = get_interval_boundaries(vec)
%
% This function takes a vector of index as input (or a logical index array)
% It returns a nx2 table containing on each line the first and last index
% of consecutive intervals of indexes.
% ex:
% A = [1 2 3 5 7 8 9] ;
% [itbound] = get_interval_boundaries(A)
% itbound =
%      1     3
%      5     5
%      7     9
% 
% 09-Oct-2011 - Hoki:  creation
% 15-Sep-2012 - Hoki: Corrected last index special case
%                       (return last idx instead of 0)
% 01-Sep-2014 - Hoki: Corrected first index special case
%                       (return [1 1] in case vec is a scalar)

%% Check vec type (logical array or direct indexing)

% Return empty vector if input is empty
itbound = [] ;
if isempty(vec)
    return
end

% Check the type of input vector
if islogical(vec)
    idxDirect = find(vec) ;

elseif isnumeric(vec)
    idxDirect = vec ;
else
    errordlg('bad type for ''vec''. Variable should be numeric or logical',mfilename,'modal')
    return
end

%% Detect intervals
Npts = length(idxDirect) ;

% return [] in case vec is all [0]
if Npts == 0 ; return ; end

itbound(1,1) = idxDirect(1) ;
% return [x x] in case vec is a scalar value [x]
if Npts == 1
    itbound(1,2) = idxDirect(1) ;
    return
end

j=1 ;
for k = 2:Npts
    if idxDirect(k)==idxDirect(k-1)+1
        if k~=Npts
            % Cycle the loop
            continue
        else
            % Last point: Assign closing boundary of last interval
            itbound(j,2) = idxDirect(k) ;
        end
    else
        % Assign closing boundary of current interval
        itbound(j,2) = idxDirect(k-1) ;
        % Assign opening boundary of next interval
        j = j + 1 ;
        itbound(j,1) = idxDirect(k) ;
        % If we're on the very last index, close the interval.
        if k==Npts
            itbound(j,2) = idxDirect(k) ;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Dear Hoki, thank you very much for your help with this. It works fine and code is easy to understand and follow. Now I will try to modify and add vertical patches for the signals that fall below the threshold 10 seconds or more. How can I rate you in this forum. Is there any link for it. Again thanks for your support, much appreciated.

Comment: @Ganesh. I'm glad the code works for you. You already upvoted and accepted my answer so there is nothing more to do to thank me. Now if other users have a similar problem to yours, they can see that my answer worked for you so they might be able to use it too. That's what this site is about ... helping other users.

Comment: Dear Hoki, yes thanks. It was of great help to me. Now I am modifying it to add shades where the data points are flagged. I am sure your solution will surely help others as well. Regards